# Ubuntu installed accidently on windows

Tags: boot

I'm new here and would very much appreciate your help

I was making a bootable USB to rescue a crashed Ubuntu notebook.

I was doing this on my Sony VIo laptop, now I can't access my Sony files, when I boot the Sony up it boots in Ubuntu

I think I have overwritten the windows boot sector with Ubuntu

I need to either undo the process or if this is not possible then at least recover my kids childhood memory photos

Any help to resolve this issue would be very much appreciated

P.s I have since removed the hardrive from the Sony and tried to read it on a windows machine as an external drive, windows can see the drive but with no data!

Answer (score 1):

since you're on Windows, you can try to recover the files by using a file recovery application such as Recuva from Piriform.

I very much doubt that the files are totally gone though if you were only trying to make a bootable USB and you would have been offered the choice of whether to wipe your hard drive by the Ubuntu installer.

Try booting a Live Linux CD such as Ubuntu which you already have. If you're not seeing files on your Sony hard drive don't panic, give Recuva a chance to recover all your files.

Last resort is running your Sony recovery discs but at the expense of losing your precious files. Google some more and never forget to make back-ups. It's the golden rule of computing - make a backup-up of a back-up of a back-up.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to mount the Windows partition from within Ubuntu if it hasn't been overwitten. This has no bearing on the MBR and can be done as follows:

Boot the USB drive and select "Try Ubuntu". Open the icon to the Home folder at the left, and in the left pane of the windows which opens, select what you presume to be your Windows partiton. If it indeed is the Windows partition, it will contain (but not be limited to) these folders:

- Windows
- Program Files

and also either `users` or `Documents and settings`. Gi onto Users if it exists; if not, Documents and settings

Enter the account under which the pictures were stored, and navigate to the correct directory. (This depends on where you put them). Now, mount your old Ubuntu partition in a new window(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), *not called `File System`, but something like `### GB Filesystem`*, and enter the `home` directory. Then, go into your username, and copy from the old window to the new window via drag-and-drop, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. You may also copy them onto a *different* flash drive, or use the CD burning tools to make a CD. Again, create backups regularly!